# How to set query timeout in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, timeout

I'm looking to see how one can set the timeout time of queries in Sequelize.

I've looked into the Sequelize docs for some info but I can't quite find what I'm looking for. The closest I have found is the "pools.acquire" option, but I'm not looking to set the timeout for an incoming connection, but rather the timeout of an ongoing query so that I may short-circuit deadlocks quickly.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html

Here is my sample code:

```
const db = new Sequelize( database, username, password, {
  host   : hostname,
  dialect: "mysql",
  define : {},
  pool: {
    max : 10,
    min : 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
})
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apparently it is not supported yet: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2072

Best thing one can do is specify the 'connectTimeout' for the mySQL 'dialectOptions'.

Answer (score 16):

add `dialectOptions`

```
  const db2 = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
    host: hostname,
    dialect: "mysql",
    define: {},
    dialectOptions: {
      options: {
        requestTimeout: 3000
      }
    },
    pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000
    },
  });
```

Comment: Warning, that answer is not valid anymore in Sequelize v5, mysql2 does not take that option anymore. Timeouts have to be handled at a query level. If you leave that option, a warning message will be displayed as follows `Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: options. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection`

Comment: The key `options` in `dialectOptions` is wrong - at least in 2023. It must be `dialectOptions: { connectTimeout: 3000 } }`

Answer (score 13):

If someone stumbles here looking for Postgres specific config (i.e. [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/api/client)) for query timeout, it looks like this in sequelize v5:

```
dialectOptions: {
  statement_timeout: 1000,
  idle_in_transaction_session_timeout: 5000
}
```

This will set statement_timeout to 1s and idle_in_transaction_session_timeout to 5s.
Ref. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/src/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js

Some of the [`node-postgres` (i.e. `require('pg')`) config options](https://node-postgres.com/api/client) re: timeouts include:

- `statement_timeout`?: number, // number of milliseconds before a statement in query will time out, default is no timeout
- `query_timeout`?: number, // number of milliseconds before a query call will timeout, default is no timeout
- `connectionTimeoutMillis`?: number, // number of milliseconds to wait for connection, default is no timeout
- `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`?: number // number of milliseconds before terminating any session with an open idle transaction, default is no timeout

Comment: if your `pg` package is too old those settings may not be supported. [pg-native doesn't support them at all at the moment](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2323)

Comment: I think I needed the `query_timeout` option, the `statement_timeout` option did not cause any timeout for me.

Comment: Or consider `connectionTimeoutMillis` option, in fact when I upgraded to Node 14, my node-postgres was failing to connect, [probably for this reason](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2317)

Answer (score 5):

For Sequelize v6 and with mysql2 driver,following code is working,

```
export const database = new Sequelize(
    Config.get('DB.NAME'),
    Config.get('DB.USER'),
    Config.get('DB.PASS'),
    {
        host: Config.get('DB.HOST'),
        port: 3306,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        dialectOptions: { connectTimeout: isDevEnv ? 15000 : 5000 }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it worked adding the requestTimeout field into dialectOptions object directly:

```
const db2 = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  host: hostname,
  dialect: "mysql",
  define: {},
  dialectOptions: {
    requestTimeout: 3000
  },
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

Sequelize version: ^4.42.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I was using my http://localhost:8888 as my port, until I changed the port to my MySQL port 8889, It looked the same apart from the last number and I had not paid much attention to see the difference, while using MAMP, you need to check your Web page that shows your MySQL server details for the port and host.

Answer (score -4):

Open local file `node_modules/_mysql@2.17.1@mysql/lib/ConnectionConfig.js`

Alter default value of `this.connectTimeout` as below:

```
  this.connectTimeout     = (options.connectTimeout === undefined)
    ? (10 * 10000)
    : options.connectTimeout;
```

Comment: You should never alter the `node_modules` because once they are reinstalled or if another developer works on your project, any change you made will be lost. And also the connectTimeout relates to the time to connect to the DB, not the time a request takes